# How to display an image in expo-av after video stopped playing?

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-av

I'm new to RN, I'm trying to create a video player using expo-av. I want to display an image once the video stopped playing. I've looked at the documentation which has VideoThumbnail, but
per my understanding, that generates a thumbnail from the video. I've a separate Jpeg file that I want to display after video ends.

How can I do that?

### Update 1:

Expo-av has `playbackStatus.didJustFinish`. Next step is to display an image in this callback function.

```
const onPlaybackStatusUpdate = useCallback(() => {
  if (playbackStatus.didJustFinish) {
    // Show image
  }
},[playbackStatus]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the poster source and style in the expo-av package.